# Spring Data Rest and Oracle Between 2 dates query giving nothing

Tags: oracle, spring-data-rest

Spring Data rest is not able to fetch the data in between 2 dates from data base table.

```
Collection<XXXX> findByCreatedOnBetween(LocalDate fromDate, LocalDate todayDate);
From Bean 
private LocalDate createdOn;
Collection<XXXX> findByCreatedOnBetween(LocalDate fromDate, LocalDate todayDate);
private LocalDate createdOn;
```

I want the data in between 2 dates:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
testing testing
WHERE
testing.created_on BETWEEN ? AND ? ;
```

Comment: The repository method looks good. If it doesn't work, then the probelm is somewhere else. Are you sure you call the proper endpoint with properly formatted dates/datetimes?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.
Yes i am calling the correct endpoint.

And my intention is 
Create a LocalDate object with the dd-MMM-yy but that is failing.

Comment: This below code is giving the same but string content of the LocalDate.But i want LocalDate with the dd-MMM-yy.


LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
  DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yy");
  String text = date.format(formatter);
  System.out.println(text.toUpperCase());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Spring Data Rest accepts only ISO 8601 date format by default (like `2018-10-22`).

If you want to accept the date in different format you need to add a converter.

```
@Configuration
public class RepositoryRestConfig extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    CustomDateConverter customDateConverter;

    @Override
    public void configureConversionService(ConfigurableConversionService conversionService) {
        conversionService.addConverter(customDateConverter);
        super.configureConversionService(conversionService);
    }
}


@Component
public class CustomDateConverter implements Converter<String, LocalDate > {

    @Override
    public LocalDate convert(String source) {
        return LocalDate.from(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yy").parse(source));
    }
}
```

Comment: I have used the above 2 components but it is not working.Always LocalDate is using the YYYY-MM-DD format.Even if i explicitly execute  the convert method.

Comment: This converter is only for converting the incoming string to localdate. if you want to render the localdate to a same format you need an other converter.